# Stop Sub Workbook_BeforeClose from rerunning at close

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is when closing my Workbook it reruns the Workbook_BeforeClose Macro. When the user clicks No it closes the ActiveWorkbook and another one that it inputs data to. When the active workbook closes it reruns the message box. It does this because it is part of the close sequence. How do i tell excel to run the code and close without running the code again. Please let me know if i can explain anything more clearly.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

MSG1 = MsgBox("Are you ready to email to MFG?", vbYesNo, "EMAIL MFG")

If MSG1 = vbYes Then

'Attaches current worksheet to new message in Outlook

If MSG1 = vbNo Then

' Enter data into separate work and close all Workbooks

INWBK.Close
Wbk.Close
End Sub
```

I also get an Error 91 on Wbk.Close, This is the Activeworkbook.

INWBK:

```
INWBK = ThisWorkbook
```

Wbk:

```
Const kPath As String = "C:\"
Const kFile As String = "QUOTE REQUEST LOG 2015.xlsm"

Rem Set Wbk in case it's open
On Error Resume Next
Set Wbk = Workbooks(kFile)
On Error GoTo 0
Rem Validate Wbk
If Wbk Is Nothing Then Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(kPath & kFile)
```

Comment: Where are you setting INWBK and Wbk?

Comment: See Above @Mark Fitzgerald

Comment: Now I'm more confused. I thought from your comment "I also get an Error 91 on Wbk.Close, This is the Activeworkbook" that Wbk was the workbook that the Workbook_BeforeClose event is running in.  Please confirm that INWBK is where the Workbook_BeforeClose event is running and Wbk is the separate "data" workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Workbook_BeforeClose` sub runs only because the workbook is being closed. Hence there is no need to put `INWBK.Close` again. After the sub finishes, the workbook window will be closed.

For the Error 91 on Wbk.Close,  the error message is `Object variable not set`. Because you calling the `Workbook_BeforeClose` twice as explained above, thus `Wbk.close` is also being called twice. The first time should be a success, but the second time, there is no object bind to it anymore, and thus Excel cried `Error 91`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- INWBK is the workbook that you are closing (i.e. it has the Workbook_BeforeClose event that is running), and
- Wbk is the secondary workbook where "data" is copied to.

There is no need to run `INWBK.Close` within your Workbook_BeforeClose event handler because INWBK is already in the process of closing.  In running `INWBK.Close` in you code, you are starting another Workbook_BeforeClose event hence the message box being displayed again.  You can confirm this by putting a break point on your `INWBK.Close` command then using F8 to step through the code from there.

I recommend deleting `INWBK.Close` from your code

An alternative would be to tell Excel to ignore the 2nd close event by adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` before displaying your message box then run `Application.EnableEvents = True` before your `End Sub`.